# Disable default options in UIMenuController for WKWebView

Tags: wkwebview, first-responder, uimenucontroller

I am developing an app with a custom subclassed WKWebView, and I am trying to disable the default options when a user selects some text inside the webview, and implement my own options. However, it seems there are 4 options that cannot be removed and will always show: Select To Here, Look Up, Learn..., and Share...

[A previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47657070/11323391) claims it's possible by overriding `canPerformAction()` or swizzling `canPerformAction` on WKContentView, but I've tried both and it hasn't worked. Specifically, there is no UIResponder selectors available for the 4 options, even though they show up when I print a list of all actions coming into `canPerformAction`.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62800027/11323391) have claimed it might be possible to disable default options if `canPerformAction()` returns false from the `First Responder`, except WKWebView refuses to become the First Responder by calling `becomeFirstResponder` while selecting text, and forcibly doing so by calling `resign` on the WKContentView seems to disable interactions with the WebView altogether. Also tried swizzling `canPerformAction` on the child WKContentView, but it seems not to make any difference.

I can only assume the default options are being handled further down the chain, but when I break the chain by setting the next UIResponder to `nil`, `canPerformAction` no longer gets called and no menu shows up anymore.

I'm at a loss here, how can I simply show a customised menu upon text selection?

Testing on
XCode 11.6
iOS 13.6

Comment: This is a very, very well asked and researched question.